# Attach a .net control to a worksheet without VSTO (but Excel-DNA)

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-dna

I'm trying to do something that I'm not sure is possible.
I want to use a .net 3rd party library that gives nice winform chart controls, to replace some (very complex and ugly) VBA generated charts in an Excel worksheet.

I'm using Excel-DNA (which is great BTW), and I managed to do all sorts of things with it, like displaying Winform forms in both sync and async way (thanks to https://github.com/Ron-Ldn/DotNetRefEdit)

So far, I managed to make my non modal form with the charts appear when I activate a particular worksheet, and by setting it's parent and topMost properties, it kinda have the expected behavior. But placing it is a real pain (different screen sizes) and I was wondering if there is a way to properly do it

So here's the question : Can I attach in some way a .Net form or a custom control to a worksheet, maybe even have it positionned relatively to a particular cell ? It must be non modal and it will display only if we are on a particular sheet.

I know with VSTO you could add a control to a worksheet, but I don't want to use VSTO. I also know that I could probably create my own ActiveX control and have it registered, and then place it in Excel like I would with another button control for example, but that seems hazardous according to what I read about it

Thank you for all ideas or suggestions

Comment: I have to add other things : I want a proper way because it doesn't seem right to display charts in a form, but I'm willing to accept it if the solution must use Forms. Also, I must not use Custom Task Panes, and recalculation isn't a problem.

Comment: Who is the end user?  Just you?  Remote co-workers? Clients?  If the user-base is small, you could try making an add-in that subscribes to Excel events (like Application.SheetActivated) and showing the form/control then.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a custom task pane (CTP) pinned to the right hand side of the Excel workbook (worksheets).

For more information on how to do this in ExcelDNA, see [ExcelDNA GitHub Sample on CTP](https://github.com/KevinT/ExcelDna/blob/master/Distribution/Samples/CustomTaskPane.dna).